# Netlify CMS: Is there a way to change default sorting of fields?

Tags: netlify, netlify-cms

Quick question, is there an option to change default sorting in Netlify CMS? I did not add any new sortingFields (just default ones). Just need to sort articles by default by `date`, instead on load it always sorts `alphabetically`

I looked through documentation but can't find it anywhere

Thank you

Comment: In the admin area there is a sort by field where you can sort by date created. Is this not what you are looking for?